# How can I reduce my crazy big backup of 460 GB of photos after I transferred my data on my iPhone 13?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

“Photos” virtually used up most of the storage space after I transferred all data to iPhone 13 from an Android device with Move to iOS App.

I stumbled upon this thread [iPhone backup takes too much space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349945/iphone-backup-takes-too-much-space/) while my iPhone 13 backup was crazy 460 GB big. It was even larger than I have storage available = 256 GB and it was really confusing because it said the storage only takes 64 GB.

- I already checked that the high resolution pics are on "High
  Efficiency" on Settings -> Camera -> Format from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205703)
- Then I found this with no answer [“Photos” used up most of the storage space after I transferred all data to iPhone13 Pro](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253191592)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My photos in reality only take about 31 GB, but due to a transfer of an old phone to this phone, it magically created duplicates worth 8000 pictures = 260 GB wtf Apple

Initially I found this helpful info https://www.ubackup.com/phone-backup/why-is-my-photo-storage-so-high.html and it said in section

**Tip 1. Clear Recently Deleted album that Apple stores deleted albums like so**

Go to **Photos** app > Tap **Albums** at the bottom > Choose **Recently Deleted** > Tap the **Select** button at the top > Choose **Delete All** to remove all photos or you may choose to delete selected photos.

With this I noticed another section **Duplicates 8000** and clicked on it. Then I joined all duplicates and additionally you need to go to **Settings** -> **General** -> **iPhone Storage** -> **Photos** -> Delete deleted Photos and boooom you get rid of 400 GB.

I really hope this helps you save some time and free up A LOT of your phones space.